# document.write not working in dynamically loaded javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've written a bookmarklet which injects an external javascript just before the closing body tag.

**The injected script contains two lines:**

```
document.write("");
alert("hello");
```

The alert works.
The document.write has no effect.

What gives?  This should clear the page, but the page remains unchanged.

Comment: You are writing an empty string in your example, so it won't have any effect.

Comment: when I do the same command in the console, it overwrites the entire document with an empty string, blanking out the page.

Comment: @ckarbass: After the page is loaded, `document.write` clears the page, and then writes the string.

Comment: correct, that's the desired behavior that is not occurring.

Comment: Works for me.  Try using the following as a bookmarklet: `javascript:(function(){document.write('');alert('hi');}())`

Comment: You're not injecting a script.

Comment: How's this?  `javascript:(function(){var script = document.createElement('script');  script.text = "document.write('');alert('hi');";  document.body.appendChild(script);}())`

Comment: Here's the bookmarklet i've written, slightly modified, to show you how I add the script.  This bookmarklet works fine: https://gist.github.com/1839509
what's not working is...once the script is loaded and fires, the document.write statement does not work.

Comment: @ckarbass: I just tested it, and you're right.  If you load an *external* js file from a bookmarklet, `document.write` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to overwrite the entire document with an empty string. you need to call `document.write` in `window.onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.write("");
}
```

When the page is rendering `document.write` just outputs the string where it is called, but after the page load it replaces the document with the string.

or call  `document.body.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: He's making a bookmarklet which is executed after the page load so this won't work I assume.

Comment: call document.body.innerHTML = ''; instead

Comment: to be specific: using document.body.innerHTML over document.write seems to work.

Comment: document.body.innerHTML sets the body content of a document so, if you assign empty string, it will clear the body from any content.

Comment: i'm more curious why document.write is not working when called from a file, but works from console or in the bookmarklet itself